# How to fix error C4930: 'AMyStaticMeshActor a(void)': prototyped function not called (was a variable definition intended?)

Tags: c++

I can't understand, how to fix error when I want to initialize object with type AMyStaticMeshActor:

```
AMyStaticMeshActor a();
```

Error is:

> error C4930: 'AMyStaticMeshActor a(void)': prototyped function not called (was a variable definition intended?)

**MyStaticMeshActor.h:**

```
#pragma once

#include "Engine/StaticMeshActor.h"
#include "MyStaticMeshActor.generated.h"

/**
 * 
 */
UCLASS()
class MYGAME_API AMyStaticMeshActor : public AStaticMeshActor
{
    GENERATED_BODY()


public:
    AMyStaticMeshActor();
    AMyStaticMeshActor(FVector location);

    // Called when the game starts or when spawned
    virtual void BeginPlay() override;

    // Called every frame
    virtual void Tick(float DeltaSeconds) override;

    UPROPERTY(EditAnywhere, Category = General)
        TSubclassOf<class AActor> WhatToSpawn;

    UPROPERTY(Category = Block, VisibleDefaultsOnly, BLueprintReadOnly, meta = (AllowPrivateAccess = "true"))
    class UBlueprint* Crystal;

};
```

**MyStaticMeshActor.cpp:**

```
#include "MyGame.h"
#include "MyStaticMeshActor.h"


AMyStaticMeshActor::AMyStaticMeshActor() {

}

AMyStaticMeshActor::AMyStaticMeshActor(FVector location) {

}

// Called when the game starts or when spawned
void AMyStaticMeshActor::BeginPlay()
{
    Super::BeginPlay();

}

// Called every frame
void AMyStaticMeshActor::Tick(float DeltaTime)
{
    Super::Tick(DeltaTime);

}
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: What do you mean by `object of the function` ?

Comment: This is MVP, you,re not declaring a variable, you're declaring a function a that takes no arguments and returns an object of type AMyStaticMeshActor, remove the parentheses.

Answer (score 3):

This is known as the [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

```
AMyStaticMeshActor a();
```

That does not create a variable called `a` of type `AMyStaticMeshActor`, it declares a function called `a` which returns a `AMyStaticMeshActor` and takes no arguments.

To fix this, just remove the parentheses:

```
AMyStaticMeshActor a;
AMyStaticMeshActor a{}; //or in C++11
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable definition is being treated as a function named `a` taking no parameters and returning a `AMyStaticMeshActor`.  To create a variable with the default constructor you can use the following:

```
AMyStaticMeshActor a;  // C++98/03

AMyStaticMeshActor a{}; //C++11 and up
```